# Jest encountered an unexpected token 'export'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test Swiper components with Jest and Testing Library but I'm getting this error. I tried to do something using `transform` and `transformIgnorePatterns` values but I couldn't fix it.

***ERROR***

```js
FAIL  src/components/BestSeller/BestSeller.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.       
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    D:\Web\nextjs-thebookstore\client\node_modules\swiper\swiper.esm.js:13
    export { default as Swiper, default } from './core/core.js';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

       9 |
      10 | const BestSeller: React.FunctionComponent<{ books: IBook[] }> = ({ books }) => {
    > 11 |   console.log(books);
         |                                          ^
      12 |   const year = new Date().getFullYear();
      13 |   SwiperCore.use([Autoplay, Grid, Navigation]);
      14 |

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/BestSeller/BestSeller.tsx:11:55)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/index.ts:20:58)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/BestSeller/BestSeller.test.tsx:7:21)
```

**jest.config.js**

```js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
 // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
 dir: './',
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
 setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
 roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
 moduleNameMapper: {
   // Handle module aliases (this will be automatically configured for you soon)
   '^@/components/src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components/$1',

   '^@/pages/src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/pages/$1',
 },
 testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
 transform: {
   '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'babel-jest',
 },
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

**BestSeller.test.tsx**

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BestSeller } from '@/components';
import React from 'react';

const DUMMY_BOOKS = [
  {
    id: '1as3ds21vcd3123dxas',
    title: 'The Silent History',
    genre: ['history, fantasy'],
    price: 32,
    discount: true,
    discountPrice: 27,
    bestSeller: true,
    featuredImage:
      'https://...',
  },
];

describe('BestSeller Component', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(<BestSeller books={DUMMY_BOOKS} />);
  });

  it('should header text render correctly', () => {
    expect(screen.getByTestId('best-seller-title')).toHaveTextContent(/bestsellers/i);
  });
});
```

**BestSeller.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay, Grid, Navigation } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { Book } from '../../components';
import { IBook } from '../../../typescript';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/grid';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';

const BestSeller: React.FunctionComponent<{ books: IBook[] }> = ({ books }) => {
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  SwiperCore.use([Autoplay, Grid, Navigation]);

  return (
    <div className="mt-10 px-4 xs:px-12 sm:20 md:px-[100px]">
      <h1 data-testid="best-seller-title" className="text-3xl sm:text-4xl font-medium">
        bestsellers
      </h1>
      <p className="text-base sm:text-lg font-thin">top selling books of {year}</p>

      <Swiper
        className="mt-6"
        grid={{ rows: 1, fill: 'row' }}
        spaceBetween={15}
        slidesPerView={1}
        breakpoints={{
          320: { slidesPerView: 1 },
          440: { slidesPerView: 2 },
          640: { slidesPerView: 3 },
          1000: { slidesPerView: 4 },
          1200: { slidesPerView: 5 },
        }}
        allowSlidePrev={true}
        allowSlideNext={true}
        navigation={true}
        loop={true}
        autoplay={{ delay: 3000, pauseOnMouseEnter: true }}
        modules={[Grid, Autoplay, Navigation]}
      >
        {books.map((book: IBook) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={book.id}>
            <Book {...book} />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BestSeller;
```

Comment: Can you add the full error message as markdown and not an image. The full error message.

Comment: You probably just need `transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!swiper)']`.

Comment: @morganney I've tried this way but I couldn't fix that. Also, I've edited the question.

Comment: I don’t see it used in your jest config. You probably used it wrong.

Comment: @Tolgahan did you ever solve this? Having the same issue currently and the transformIgnorePatterns does not work